# Firestore Failed to merge array of items to another array using FieldValue.arrayUnion()

Tags: arrays, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that invoked when a certain event happened. In the function i will get an array of string for example `let h:string[] = ["foo","bar","baz"]` something similar to this when I try to update an array field inside my document like this
 `names: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(h)` it failed to do that and throw that error in the console

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert an array value in an array value.
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
    at callback (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)
```

But if i changed the code to this 
`names: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("foo","bar","baz")` it works but in my function, i receive an array not the above format so it fails

Here is what I want. I have an array field in the document let call it names. when the function is triggered and I get the array from it. I want to add this array to the existing names array

before adding the array `names : ["test","test2"]`

after adding the array `names : ["test","test2","foo","bar","baz"]`

How to fix that?
I'm using typescript  3.0.1

Comment: Not quite following but if admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("foo","bar","baz") works then admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion.apply(null,h) should also work.

Comment: if names=["test","test2"] and otherArray=["foo","bar","baz"] then names.concat(otherArray) would be ["test","test2","foo","bar","baz"]

Comment: The first one worked! Thank you very much you saved my day :)

Comment: I've written it up as an answer. If it was helpful then please mark my answer as the solution.

Comment: Sure! i will mark it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("foo","bar","baz")` works then we can use a function called [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)  which exists as an object member on every function... It's a very useful one to know. Apply 'applys' a single array of arguments to the function (rather than comma separated arguments) and invokes it.

Hence the solution is:

```
admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion.apply(null,h)
```

Answer (score 5):

The arrayUnion function have a array value on definition, you need add your array to this array value, on javascript or type you can use ...(NameArray) to union.

```
items : any[] = [1,2,4,5,67,8];
admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...items);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's always useful to add some explanation why your code answers the question.